# Tikz: conflicts related to a macro-defined environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgffor

I intend to draw three points on a circle into a macro-defined axis environment. The code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\newenvironment{mytikzaxis}[9]{\begin{axis}[
    axis line style={->},
    axis equal,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$#1$,
    ylabel=$#2$,
    xmin=#3,
    xmax=#4,
    ymin=#5,
    ymax=#6,
    xtick={#7},
    ytick={#8},
    #9
    ]
}
{\end{axis}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.69,>=stealth] %
    \begin{mytikzaxis}{x}{y}{-1.2}{1.4}{-1.2}{1.4}{1}{1}{}
        % circle 
        \draw[radius=1] (0,0) circle;
        % roots of unity
        \foreach \a in {0,120,240} {
            \draw[red,only marks] plot [only marks, mark=*] ({cos(\a)},{sin(\a)});
        }

    \end{mytikzaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces an error with a - for me - cryptic error message: `\GenericError  ...                                 #4  \errhelp \@err@     ... l.34    \end{standardtikzaxis}`

I can make it compile by

- commenting out the drawing of the points (line 31), drawing only the axes...
- commenting out the macro/environment (lines 25 and 34) drawing only circle and points...
- but: also by commenting out macro argument #6 (line 15) which seems really strange to me

I have absolutely no idea even where to look for the error.

Comment: it dies horribly expanding the standard latex `\a` command, if you replace `\a` by some new name say `\qqqa` you get  `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> {cos(\qqqa ` not sure what it should be instead...

Comment: This might be a typical PGFPlots-`\foreach` problem. The `\addplot`s don't get “executed” right away but stored for later. (I realize now that you don't even use `\addplot` – why?) At that point, the definition of the loop variable `\a` is lost. In your simple case, you should be able to use [`\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/utility-commands). By the way, TikZ has polar coordinate, your `(r * sin α, r * cos α)` can be replaced by `(α:r)` (in your case *r* is 1).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: using \pgfplotsinvokeforeach indeed solves the problem, thx! To your question: no specific reason, I am just more used to \draw. Is addplot the better choice.